# Can you emulate Windows filesystem case semantics with ntfs-3g?

Tags: linux, ntfs-3g, case-sensitivity

With NTFS on a Windows machine if you create a directory "ABC" and then try to create a directory "abc" it will be rejected because Windows considers it the same name.

Now on Linux the standard ntfs-3g filesystem doesn't suffer this (NTFS, itself, allows for both... it's just Windows doesn't).

I've found that `-t lowntfs-3g -o ignore_case` will produce the error, but it does this by forcing everything to lower case.  `mkdir ABC` results in `abc`.

Is there a way of using NTFS on Linux that follows what Windows would do?  Retains the case for display purposes, but acts case insensitive for operations?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way of using NTFS on Linux that follows what Windows would do? Retains the case for display purposes, but acts case insensitive for operations?

*Display purposes* is something the system is not aware of, it just reads directory entries from the filesystem. So it is not possible both retain the case and ignore it *at the same time*.

That's because the filesystem implementation cannot know if it's reading the information (via `openat()/fstat()` for example) for `ls` or, say, for `cat`.

Note that although `-t lowntfs-3g -o ignore_case` will *show* lowercase, it will preserve the original case. You can check that with two mount sessions:

Create the filesystem:

```
# dd if=/dev/zero of=/tmp/ntfs bs=1M count=100
# mkfs.ntfs -F /tmp/ntfs
```

Now, with ignore_case (and lowercase) create `AbC`:

```
# mount.lowntfs-3g -o ignore_case /tmp/ntfs /mnt
# mkdir /mnt/AbC
# ls /mnt
abc
# umount /mnt
```

afterwards, umounting and re mounting the same filesystem without case conversion:

```
# mount.ntfs  /tmp/ntfs /mnt
# ls /mnt
AbC
# umount /mnt
```

What you want to achieve is doable though. Just not, from what I see, with `ntfs-3g` current implementation. You could have that behavior (after all Windows does it) with a customized `ls` or file explorer. Preloading `readdir()` for example also looks like something that might work.

Comment: Well, it's more than `ls`; affects many calls such as `mkdir()` `open()` `readdir()` and more.  Anything that deals with filenames, really!

Comment: @StephenHarris I get your point and you are right but in my answer I mentioned preload *just* for whatever file manager/listing program the OP uses, since it seems to be mostly a display issue. Trying to replicate Windows behaviour across the board with preloads would be messy and break things ... not worth it. For the file manager, it is a manageable number of calls, I think. In no way I'd recommend that though. I was only trying to see if there was a way to solve it.